# Google Play Music on Alarm

Tags: ios, itunes, music, iphone

I'm new to iOS, I've come from Android and to avoid loosing time migrating all the musics from Google Play Music to iTunes *(and since Google allows you to have 50,000 songs on their servers for free that can be accessible on any device with a Google account)*, I decided to keep using Google Play Music on the iPhone.

But if I want to set the alarm it only lets me choose ring tones from the iPhone or musics from iTunes.

Does anyone knows if it's there any way to set Google Play Music musics to the alarm?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such functionality is not supported by the built-in alarm for iPhone unless the music is stored in the Music app of the phone. You would have to see if there is a third-party app which can pull from Google Play music.